# Proving a Language is Regular via Automata

Tags: formal-languages, automata, regular-language

Let $L_1, L_2$ be regular languages over $\Sigma = \{ a,b,c\}$. Prove that the following language is regular as well:

$$L = \{ x\in \Sigma^* | x = uvw; \\ u,v,w \in L_1 ; \\wvu\in L_2;\\ W^R\in L[a^*b^*] \}$$

I think I have to build an automata for this question, involving $L_1, L_2$, since they're regular, but how?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by $W^R \in L[a^*,b^*]$?

Comment: this is just what the question says :-|

Answer (score 1):

Your language is the intersection of two languages which are both regular. Linking 3 times $L_1$ and $L_2^{-1}$ thus regular.

Comment: What is $L_2^{-1}$?

Comment: This is wrong! $L$ isn't the said intersection since you have the parts $u,v$ and $w$. The $L_2^{-1}$ isn't the reversal or anything!

Comment: $L_2^{-1} = \{ u_n u_{n-1} ... u_2 u_1 : u_1 ... u_n \in L_2\}$